# Passing Form Values to Child Components in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have a problem separating the form to the other components. I need to put all the logic/functionalities in the parent/main component and display it on child components. Like the submit function should be on the parent component.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-form-validation-jabfuq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
   <form [formGroup]="personalInfoForm" (ngSubmit)="onRegister(personalInfoForm)">
       <app-personal-info [personalInfoForm]="personalInfoForm" [submitted]="submitted"></app-personal-info>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code had multiple issues:

1. you can't access the `FormGroup` properties directly you need to
   use a getter i.e `.get('email')`
2. you need to put the submit button next to the parent form, not inside the child component

[stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12-form-validation-shb7v9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpersonal-info%2Fpersonal-info.component.ts)

Comment: This is good but I wanted the onSubmit on the main/parent component

Comment: oh ok i didn't check your parent component, i fixed the example

Comment: Thanks. Why is it in my app, there is error saying "Object is possibly 'null'. this is due to the error messages on the inputs.